# Type \'Observable<{}>\' is not assignable to type in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

Observable is unable to assigend, my package.json file holds

```
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
"systemjs": "0.19.24",
"es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "0.6.12"
```

Problem happens while my terminal start compiling it shows me an errormessage

message:

> '\u001b[31mresources/assets/typescript/services/user.service.ts(25,5): \u001b[39merror TS2322: Type \'Observable<{}>\' is not assignable to type \'Observable\'.\n  Type \'{}\' is not assignable to type \'User[]\'.\n    Property \'length\' is missing in type \'{}\'.' }

in my service component this.loggedUser$ is unable to initialised by new Observable inside the constructor and it breaks the whole thing.

This is my service component

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http,Response,Headers} from 'angular2/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {User} from '../interfaces/interfaces';
export var API_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:8080/api';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  loggedUser$: Observable<User[]>; 
  private loggedUserObserver: Observer<User[]>;
  private loggedUserInfo:{
        users: User[]
    };

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.loggedUser$ = new Observable(observer => this.loggedUserObserver = observer).share();
    this.loggedUserInfo = { users: [] };
  }


    getLoggedUser(){
      return this._http.get(API_ENDPOINT+'/getLoggedUser')
      .map((res:Response)=>res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { 
        this.loggedUserInfo.users = data;
        this.loggedUserObserver.next(this.loggedUserInfo.users);
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log(this.loggedUserInfo.users)
      );
    }


}
```

in my interface I have

```
export interface User {
    id?: number,    
    name?: string,
    email?:string,
    email2?: string,
    password?: string,
    mobile?: string,
    profilePicture?:string,
    userTimeZone?: string
}
```

if i place a type in the constructor like

```
this.loggedUser$ = new Observable<User[]>(observer => this.loggedUserObserver = observer).share();
```

then it shows me a different error on the app component, the error is not coming in the terminal its coming on the console and it is
EXCEPTION: TypeError: _this.loggedUserObserver is undefined

```
import {Component,OnInit,} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {RouteConfig, RouteData} from 'angular2/router';

import {MyProfileComponent} from './settings/my-profile.component';
import {MyCompaniesComponent} from './company/my-companies.component';
import {MyTasksComponent} from './tasks/my-tasks.component';
import {UserComponent} from './user/user.component';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';
import {User} from './interfaces/interfaces';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    //templateUrl: 'appView/front.html',
    template:`{{loggedUser.name}}`,
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, MyProfileComponent, MyCompaniesComponent,UserComponent],
    providers: [UserService],


})

export class AppComponent{  
    loggedUser: Observable<User[]>;
    loggedUserInfo:User;
    constructor (private _userService: UserService){    
    }


    ngOnInit(){
        this.loggedUser = this._userService.loggedUser$;
        this._userService.getLoggedUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a type for your new Observable in the constructor? I think the error message points that out to you.

Comment: i tried with this but it drive me to a new error, in my app component i have [code]this export class AppComponent{  
    loggedUser: Observable<{}>;
    loggedUserInfo:User;
    constructor (private _userService: UserService){    
    }

    
    ngOnInit(){
        this.loggedUser = this._userService.loggedUser$;
        this._userService.getLoggedUser();
    }
}[/code] and now it tells me that loggedUserObserver is not defined

Comment: please look at my updated question, your solution takes the error from the terminal but throws an exception on the console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searched a lot and comments from #majodi also helped.
In the service.ts i have initialised my variable like this

```
loggedUser$: Observable<User[]>;  
loggedUserObserver: Observer<User[]>;
loggedUserInfo:User[];
```

and in the service constructor

```
constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.loggedUser$ = new Observable<User[]>(
      observer => {
      this.loggedUserObserver = observer;
    }
    ).share();
}
```

and in the app.component.ts file i have called my observable this way

```
ngOnInit(){     
    this._userService.loggedUser$.subscribe(latestData => {
       this.loggedUserInfo1 = latestData;

    });      
    this._userService.getLoggedUser(); 
}
```

and these solved the issue.